# Looking for a .NET "text" editor control

Tags: .net, winforms, controls, textbox

My boss is looking for a .NET text control to build a custom editor on. Here’s what we need it to do:

- Supports embedded tables, with easily editing (like Word tables).
- Supports different text styles (font, size, color, background, etc).
- Ability to programmatically set styles, both on first load, and as file is edited.
- Supports key/mouse catching events and changing behavior.
- Supports *large* documents (10's to 100's of klocs) without losing performance.
- Not a full up word processing control, but more an advanced text control.
- We don’t need to support .rtf, .html, etc. Instead, we need to be able to on the fly translate our data into the text editor control and back out as well, presumably by dynamically creating tables, indentation levels, etc.

We have looked at and rejected a few options including [TX Text Control](http://www.textcontrol.com/) (because its table editing is not good enough, specifically its column editing abilities)

---

edit:

- must support stand alone use.

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by "stand alone use" ?

Comment: I really don't remember what I was referring to. I *think* I might have been rejecting web based solutions.

Comment: Have you looked at Nevron Text Editor? - https://www.nevron.com/products-open-vision-nov-rich-text-editor-control-overview.aspx. 
It does support insert/remove rows/cols as well as various table interactive resize modes

Comment: @user896851 - just tried nevron and the sample locks up on pasting a 17K line text file or 284 pages - where both Word and Notepad handle it fine.

Answer (score 2):

Try the [editor](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/editor.aspx) control from [telerik](http://www.telerik.com/). have a look at the [demos](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/Editor/Examples/Overview/DefaultCS.aspx) and see if it's any good for you.

Comment: Yeah, if I'd have seen the stand alone use bit I'd have kept on browsing :o)

Comment: I added it after you answered.

Comment: Who the <blank> down-voted this?! it's a fine answer for users with related questions!

Comment: I use the Telerik editor control and find it very flexible and quite reliable.  So, +1 from me.

RE: downvoting - it has become a real habit for lots of people.  If you don't like the Telerik control, then at least explain that.  If you like something else better then put your own answer in and see who gets upvoted the most.

Comment: it is sluggish on large file sizes - almost useless imo but I didn't down vote :)

Answer (score 0):

How about hosting the [The WPF RichTextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox.aspx) control [in WinForms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.elementhost.aspx).

Comment: That was what we ended up trying, but it had performance and scaling issues. (We eventually dropped the motivating design and when with something else)

Comment: Really? I guess the WPF-based editor in VS 2010 is not built on the RichTextBox control then :)

Comment: Have you seen the WPF RichTextBox? - it is a joke

Answer (score 0):

Similar in spirit to Telerik answer...  Have you considered DevExpress rich edit control?
They also nave a nice app framework to build your app.